# Optimizing order by clause in join query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I need help in optimizing this query.

```
  SELECT messages.*
   FROM messages
   INNER JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
   WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

Without the limit, this query returns 200K rows and takes about 1.3 - 2 seconds to run.  The problem seems to be in the order by clause.  Without it, the query takes .0005 seconds .

```
Indexes:
    ( subscription.user_id, subscription.entity_id )
    ( subscription.entity_id )
    ( messages.timestamp )
    ( messages.entity_id, messages.timestamp )
```

I was able to improve the performance by changing the query to this:

```
SELECT messages.* FROM messages
INNER JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id 
INNER JOIN ( 
   SELECT message_id FROM messages ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) as temp on temp.messsage_id = messages.message_id
WHERE subscription.user_id = 1 LIMIT 50
```

This runs in .12 seconds.  A very nice improvement but i'd like to know if it could be better. It seems
If I could somehow filter the 2nd inner join then things will be faster.

Thanks.

SCHEMA:

```
   messages 
      message_id, entity_id, message, timestamp

   subscription
      user_id, entity_id
```

**UPDATE**

Raymond Nijland's Answer solves my initial problem, but another just cropped up

```
 SELECT messages.*
   FROM messages
   STRAIGHT_JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
   WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

The straight join is inefficient in two cases:

1. there is no user_id entry in the subscription table
2. there are few relevant entries in the messages table

Any suggestions on how to fix this? if not from a query perspective, an application one?

**UPDATE**

EXPLAIN INFO

LIMIT 50

```
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                           | key           | key_len | ref                                    | rows | Extra       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages          | index  | idx_timestamp                           | idx_timestamp | 4       | NULL                                   |   50 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subscription      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,entity_id,user_id               | PRIMARY       | 16      | const, messages.entity_id              |    1 | Using index |
```

Without Limit

```
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                           | key           | key_len | ref                                    |   rows   | Extra         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages          | ALL    | entity_id_2,entity_id                   | NULL          | NULL    | NUL                                    |   255069 | Using filesort|
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subscription      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,entity_id,user_id               | PRIMARY       | 16      | const, messages.entity_id              |        1 | Using index   |
```

CREATE TABLE STATEMENTS:

With ~5000 rows

```
subscription | CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
  `user_id`   bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`entity_id`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

with ~255,000 rows

```
messages | CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `message_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `idx_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Can you post the show create table statements?

Comment: 200 thousand rows for a single user?  Are you sure about that?

Comment: @DanBracuk yes I am sure

Comment: Can you run an EXPLAIN on no user_id case and  few relevant entries in the messages case  and post the results here?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Updated post with explain info

Comment: What querys does trigger this explain can you also mention this?

Comment: Both, cases trigger this explain:  no user_id, and few message entries

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the index messages.entity_id this one is Redundant and try an straight_join i think the mysql optimizer is accesing your tables in the wrong order.
MySQL need to access table messages first so it can use the index on messages(entity_id, timestamp) and remove the need for an "Using temporary; Using filesort" (what is slow if MySQL needs to create an MyISAM disk based table and needed to sort (quicksort algoritm) this with disk I/O reads and I/O writes).

```
 SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN messages.*
   FROM messages
   INNER JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
   WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

OR

```
 SELECT messages.*
   FROM messages
   STRAIGHT_JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
   WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

I've also had this problem and i fixed it like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b34870/1 but then with Country / City tables

**Edit because off Jason M reaction on the STRAIGHT_JOIN**

The straight join is inefficient in two cases:

**there is no user_id entry in the subscription table**

Indeed the MySQL optimizer with INNER JOIN would trigger an "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables" and never executes the query.
But an STRAIGHT_JOIN doens't trigger an  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables" so an (maybe full) index scan needs to be done to find it's user_id value that could slow down query execution. 
**Easy fix would be: use existing user_id's with the STRAIGHT_JOIN**

**there are few relevant entries in the messages table**

Possible same problem here MySQL thinks it should do an (maybe full) index scan to find results. but i need to see an EXPLAIN statement to know for sure

You may also want to try this query first

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

 SELECT
  entity_id

 FROM
  subscriptions

 WHERE
  subscription.user_id = 1 
)
 subscriptions

INNER JOIN 
 messages

ON
 subscriptions.entity_id = messages.entity_id

ORDER BY
 messages.timestamp DESC

LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Filesort is not necessarily slow. And is a misnomer, it does **not** mean that is performed through a disk file!

Comment: i know... I mean the combination "Using temporary; Using filesort" what could result in sorting an MyISAM disk based temporary table with quicksort algorithm and lot of disk IO

Comment: Thanks Raymond, this absolutely solved my problem.  Query now runs in .000x seconds

Comment: @ypercube and i'am not complety sure filesort will NOT trigger disk based IO because off this line   IO_CACHE tempfile, buffpek_pointers, *outfile;  in sql/filesort.cc  this means that an filesort could trigger some disk bases IO writes and reads   but i've not completly analysed this part off the source code

Comment: @Jason M tip next time run an EXPLAIN then you can see in what order MySQL will try to access your tables.. if you use GROUP BY/ORDER BY on table one. MySQL needs to read table one first. And if this is the wrong order force it with an STRAIGHT_JOIN. also not the MYSQL optimizer is cost based if table one has lesser records this table will be accessed first if table two has lesser records this table will be accessed first..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the tip. Didn't know about the cost based behavior and it explains what was happening.  Also did't know about straight_joins.

Comment: @RaymondNijland There seems to be an issue when the user_id doesn't exist in the subscription table.  This query takes about 1.7 seconds to return zero results.  Do you know of any fix for this?

Comment: @RaymondNijland There seesms to be a trade off between straight and inner joins.  When there is a large number of relevant rows in subscriptions, the straight join works very fast.  However, when there aren't, it works slowly.

Comment: @RaymondNijland not sure if my previous response is entirely correct, it seems that if there aren't a lot of relevant entries in the messages table, the straight join will run slower. So, in summary: if there are no entries in the subscription table == slow, if there are few entries in messages == slow

Comment: @RaymondNijland I tried your other query, it is quick for when there are few messages and/or no user_id in the subscription table.  In the other case, the query time averages 1.9 seconds